# Executor self-exiting due to : Unable to create executor due to URI has an authority component

Tags: spark-streaming, amazon-eks, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming, spark-operator

We are working on a project where we have to deploy our application on a Spark cluster( based upon EKS). We are using Spark-Operator to manage our Spark cluster.

Application Nature:
My application is based on Spark's "structured streaming". It streams events from the Kafka topic with 5 partitions.

The application is almost get deployed using the help from AWS for Spark Operator ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/spark-operator-gs.html)) but it is not able to start the executors. It gets exit with the below error:

```
23/07/10 12:50:16 INFO Executor: Fetching file://usr/lib/jars/java-word-count.jar with timestamp 1688993383773
23/07/10 12:50:16 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Unable to create executor due to URI has an authority component
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:425)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:778)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:537)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13(Executor.scala:962)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13$adapted(Executor.scala:954)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:985)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:954)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
23/07/10 12:50:16 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
23/07/10 12:50:16 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/07/10 12:50:16 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
```

And pod yaml is :

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-mango
  namespace: spark-operator
spec:
  type: Java
  mode: cluster
  #image: "755674844232.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-6.11.0:latest"
  image: "603016229198.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/emr6.geomango_spark_cluster"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainClass: com.ageon.geomango.WordCount
  arguments:
   - "b-4.geomangoemrdemo.pzs37h.c12.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.geomangoemrdemo.pzs37h.c12.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-9.geomangoemrdemo.pzs37h.c12.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092"
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///usr/lib/jars/java-word-count.jar"
  sparkVersion: "3.3.1"
  hadoopConf:
   # EMRFS filesystem
   fs.s3.customAWSCredentialsProvider: com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider
   fs.s3.impl: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem
   fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.EMRFSDelegate
   fs.s3.buffer.dir: /mnt/s3
   fs.s3.getObject.initialSocketTimeoutMilliseconds: "2000"
   mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem: "2"
   mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem: "true"
 
  sparkConf: 
    
    # Required for EMR Runtime
    spark.driver.extraClassPath: /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*
    spark.driver.extraLibraryPath: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
    spark.executor.extraClassPath: /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*
    spark.executor.extraLibraryPath: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
  
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  volumes:
    - name: efs-spark-operator
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: efs-storage-claim
    - name: efs-spark-operator-executors
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: efs-storage-claim-executors
  driver:
    cores: 2
    memory: "9g"
    labels:
      version: 3.3.2    
    nodeSelector: 
      emrtype: sf-emr-on-spot
    serviceAccount: driver-account-sa
    volumeMounts:
      - name: efs-spark-operator
        mountPath: /mnt1    
  executor:
    cores: 2
    instances: 1
    memory: "9g"
    nodeSelector: 
      emrtype: sf-emr-on-spot
    labels:
      version: 3.3.2
    volumeMounts:
      - name: efs-spark-operator-executors
        mountPath: /mnt1
```

Any help will be much appreciated.